# crawl playstore with python and phantomjs

Tags: python, web-scraping, phantomjs, web-crawler

This code will crawl again from the beginning every time an error occurs. I want to change this to crawl only new text, not just from the beginning.
and  I would like to ask for further advice.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd

#Setting up Chrome webdriver Options
#chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#setting  up local path of chrome binary file
#chrome_options.binary_location = "/Users/Norefly/chromedriver2/chromedriver.exec"
#creating Chrome webdriver instance with the set chrome_options
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS("C:/Python/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe")
link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.supercell.clashofclans&hl=en"
driver.get(link)
#driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)")
Ptitle = driver.find_element_by_class_name('id-app-title').text.replace(' ','')
print(Ptitle)
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body-content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/button[2]/div[2]').click()

sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body-content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/button[2]/div[2]/div/div').click()
#select_newest.select_by_visible_text('Newest')
#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body-    content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/button[2]/div[2]/div/div').click()
sleep(2)
#driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.review-filter.id-review-sort-filter.dropdown-menu-container').click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.displayed-child').click()
#driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-dropdown-value='1']").click()

driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('button.dropdown-child')[0].click()")
reviews_df = []
for i in range(1,10):
try:
    for elem in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('single-review'):

        print(str(i))
        content = elem.get_attribute('outerHTML')
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
        #print(soup.prettify())
        date = soup.find('span',class_='review-date').get_text()
        rating = soup.find('div',class_='tiny-star')['aria-label'][6:7]
        title = soup.find('span',class_='review-title').get_text()
        txt = soup.find('div',class_='review-body').get_text().replace('Full Review','')[len(title)+1:]
        print(soup.get_text())
        temp = pd.DataFrame({'Date':date,'Rating':rating,'Review Title':title,'Review Text':txt},index=[0])
        print('-'*10)
        reviews_df.append(temp)
        #print(elem)
    except:
        print('what i can do?')
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body-content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/button[2]/div[2]/div/div').click()
        #driver.execute_script("document.querySelectorAll('button.dropdown-child')[0].click()")
        #driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body-content"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/button[2]/div[2]/div/div').click()

reviews_df = pd.concat(reviews_df,ignore_index=True)

reviews_df.to_csv(Ptitle+'review_google.csv', encoding='utf-8')

driver.close()
```

And I wonder if this is a problem with phantom js

Comment: "And I wonder if this is a problem with phantom js" ... who knows? You didn't post the error message you are getting.

Comment: no The code works fine  but print is first text   
It is collected from the beginning.
So I want to fix that the first text only gets collected repeatedly

Comment: Sorry I am having trouble understanding your English.